# Java native methods issues with SUN JVM (jdk1.5.0_14) and multi-core CPU’s

Tags: arrays, jvm, native, jrockit

We are hosting an application on SUN JVM that handles a lot of XML parsing using Jaxb.
The application is parsing the XML fine using JRockit 5 but when using the SUN JVM the JVM spends a majority of it’s time on native methods such as java-lang.System.arraycopy, 
java.lang.String.intern and java.lang.ClassLoader.getPackage.
The CPU load is approx. 60% higher when using SUN JVM compared with JRockit.

Even stranger is that when we only run the application server using one core (in WMWare) the problem disappears.

Has anyone experienced the same behavior?

Mattias Arnersten